# The Terraform Provider Mastercard/Terraform-provider-restapi uses a data field to send json data to a rest api but the api expects parameter json_data

Tags: api, rest, terraform

When I use the Mastercard/Terraform-provider-restapi and I send json data using the resource I receive an error back from the API

> "{"code":3,"message":"Error: Missing parameter 'json_data'"}: timestamp=2022-06-30T10:51:01.012+0100"

So it seems that the API I am trying to send data to is expecting a json_data parameter.
Any idea how to get this provider/resource to send the json data using a json_data parameter?

**Here is my code:**

```
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        restapi = {
          source               = "Mastercard/restapi"
          version              = "1.17.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "restapi" {
        uri                  = "${var.uri}"
        debug                = true
        write_returns_object = true
        username = "${var.auth_user}"
        password = "${var.auth_passwd}"
    
        headers = {
            "Content-Type" = "application/json"
        }
        create_method  = "POST"
    }
    
    resource "restapi_object" "post_request" {
        path = "/webservices/rest.php?version=1.2"
        data = "{\"operation\": \"core/create\", <remaining valid json removed for clarity>}
    }
```

Here's the provider of the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Mastercard/restapi/latest/docs).

Comment: I would strongly suggest using the built-in `jsonencode` function for this kind of data.

Comment: This is due to the usage for the cURL bindings to Go (`http.Client`) in the provider. The exact root cause is ambiguous as to whether it is unusual endpoint parameters for the specific REST API, or some usage update in the bindings incorporated into a recent provider update. Either way you need to raise an issue on the tracker asking for help from a maintainer.

Comment: @Alral how do I run the fakeserver to be able to test this provider. Note I am on windows

Comment: Could you not use the http data source instead? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http